# Make ajax call in loop

Tags: vue.js, babeljs, axios

I'm trying to make an ajax call in a loop. But it looks like we can't, so i'm wondering how can i avoid this situation.

I'm making a search, and i have this method who format the data :

```
async formatSearchUserByNameResults(results) {
        if (results.length > 0) {
          results.forEach((element) => {
            const currentUserData = await user.getUserById(element.id);
            const aResult = searchBuilders.userBuilder(element);
            aResult.following = currentUserData.folliwing;
            this.searchResults.push(aResult);
          });
        }
      },
```

The getUserById function make an ajax call :

```
async getUserById(userId) {
    const response = await axios.get(`${config.baseUrl}/users/${userId}`, { withCredentials: true });
    return response.data;
  }
```

But i always get this error :

> Parsing error: await is a reserved word

Because forEach is synchronous.

Is there any alternative to make an ajax call in a loop ?

Thanks

Comment: That's super inefficient, what are you really trying to achieve that brought you to this solution?

Comment: I would suggest you don't need await/async on `formatSearchUserByNameResults` since you already have it on `getUserById` (where the get is).

Comment: BTW, you don't need `if (results.length > 0) {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you get that particular error but one issue could be that the anonymous function you're passing into the forEach() is not an async function.

Try `async (element) => { ...`

I would avoid having async functions where you're not tracking the result of whether they're complete. You could probably wrap them into a Promise.all() or something like that to know if they've completed or not.